# Is this possible? : HashMap<String, char>

Tags: java, string, char, hashmap

I'm creating a game with two boards:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpWlO.jpg

I want to link the "A" to the ".". Both are string Arrays.
I want to use this:

```
indexesOfBoard.put("A", ((morris.START[0].charAt(0))));
```

But then I get an error like:

```
The method put(String, String) in the type HashMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, char)
```

And if I change the HashMap to `< String, char>` I'll get:

```
Syntax error on token "char", Dimensions expected after this token
```

Comment: Use `Character`. You need to use Objects not primitives

Comment: BTW if you're interested in the meaning of your error, `Map<String, char[]>` is legal, so the compiler expects those array brackets to be added.

Answer (score 11):

Type arguments cannot be primitive types. Use wrapper class alternative instead:

```
HashMap<String, Character>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primitive type is not allowed in generic class, only class type is allowed. use like this.

```
HashMap<String, Character>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use primitive types in generics. Use `Character` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types may not be used as generic typeparameters in java. Use the corresponding boxed type instead.

Answer (score 0):

*Primitive types* are not allowed in Type arguments. It expects containers (objects) not primitives. You have to use Wrapper objects `Character` instead of primitive `char` type

Use : `HashMap<String,Character>`

After declaring the reference type as `HashMap<String,Character>` , you can simply put `char` primitive as value into it. This is where auto-boxing comes into picture. i.e *it boxes char into Character object* and store it

Comment: this is not specific for HashMap.

Comment: Yes, i just answered specifically. i just updated it

Answer (score 0):

Error is because You are using char(Primitive type).
Try Using.

HashMap<**String**, **Character**>.